# Is it possible to "reset" the read/write layer of a Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-layer

While reading about containers and their layers (https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver), it come to my mind the following question:

Is it possible to "reset" the read/write layer of a Docker container? 
By "reset" I mean to delete all the state the container may have written to that layer -- so I can get a "brand new container" whiteout having to start a new one.

Comment: Why not just delete and recreate the container?  It seems like that would have the effect you want?

Comment: For sure it will, @DavidMaze! Thing is that for some "heavy" containers the initialisation step may take longer than we are willing to wait for... so I'm trying to figure out if there is something I can do to speed things up :)